# Where/how share annotated datasets (curated by humans)?

Tags: dataset

Once we have invested resources into annotating and reviewing some datasets (manually, by humans) how should we proceed to share them?

How can we make them findable and accessible? Is it possible to monetize them? Is there a go-to repository for golden standard datasets that would classify, organize and make them available through their API?

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. To my knowledge datasets are generally described in a research article first. Which domain is the dataset about? In NLP for instance there are commercial distributors who can be contacted. I assume that it would be specific to the domain.

Answer (score 0):

[SnowFlake Marketplace](https://www.snowflake.com/en/data-cloud/marketplace/)

> The Snowflake Marketplace utilizes Snowflake Secure Data Sharing to
> connect providers of data with consumers.